# changing soap body attribute in perl SOAP::Lite 0.7

Tags: perl, soap-client

Is it possible to set an attribute in the `soap:Body` tag using perl and `SOAP::Lite 0.7.`

In all the examples I have seen I can change the attributes inside the body tag using

SOAP::Data * calls and use the `$soap->call($dataValue)` for this purpose.

What I really need is the way to add an ID attribute to the `soap:Body` tag in `SOAP::Lite perl`. Any pointers in this direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think after banging my head on wall for 2days I should giveup using soap lite at client side and use raw xml for this purpose or use one of the alternates. I needed this to add the digital signatures. Found some suggestions to switch to SOAP::Simple/XML::Compile::SOAP. Any pointers in the direction would still be helpful. thanks

Also found out the way to have fine grain control via extending SOAP::Serializer and overriding the envelop method.